# unexpectedly found nil while unwapping an Optional value エラーが出る

Tags: ios, swift

swift＆オブジェクト指向触りたての初心者です．
凄く初歩的な質問だと思いますが，お答えいただけると幸いです．

現在，ViewControllerクラスにあるメソッドを別の（Testという名前の）クラスから呼びだそうとしています．その際，unexpectedly found nil while unwapping an Optional valueというエラーがでて停止してしまいます．原因が分からず困っています・・・．

色々回っている際，`var viewController:ViewController!` の部分を `var viewController＝ViewController()` と書いているところもあり，どちらが正しいのかもわからない状態です．

よろしくお願いいたします．

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit //impot KIt..

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{

    private var myImageView:UIImageView!
    var myLabel: UILabel!
    let Ex = Test()

    @IBOutlet weak var status: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() { //make function.

        super.viewDidLoad()
        //background image
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "cotton-a.png")!)
        Ex.ex()

    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    func test(){
        myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 100))

        var image : UIImage?

        image = UIImage(named: "check.png")
        myImageView.image = image
        myImageView.layer.position = CGPoint(x:self.view.bounds.width/2,y:self.view.bounds.height/2)

        self.view.addSubview(myImageView)

    }
}
```

Test.swift

```
import Foundation

class Test: NSObject {
    var viewController:ViewController!

    func ex(){

        for var i=0 ; i<10 ; i++ {

            println("i is \(i)")

            if(i==9){
                //次でエラーが出て落ちる．
                viewController.test()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Test.swift

var viewController:ViewController!
```

宣言時、記号`!`がついた変数は、*Implicitly unwrapped optional*といいますが、*Optional*型であることに変わりはなく、値が`nil`である可能性があります。プログラマの責任において、なにか値を代入して、`nil`にならないようにすることを求められます。*Implicitly unwrapped optional*を使う場合は、できるだけ早期に、代入をしましょう。現状のプログラムでは、なにも代入していないので、「Optionalの値にnilが見つかったよ」というエラーダイアログが出ます。
`UIViewController`のサブクラスでは、`viewDidLoad`メソッドで、インスタンスの初期化をすることが多いですが、クラス一般でいうなら、イニシアライザで初期化するのが望ましい処理です。*Implicitly unwrapped optional*のインスタンス変数（プロパティ）への代入も、イニシアライザで行いましょう。

```
class Test: NSObject {

    weak var viewController:ViewController! // 循環参照を予防する意味で、weak属性をしています。

    init(viewController: ViewController) {
        self.viewController = viewController
    }
    ........
}
```

イニシアライザに引数を持たせることで、例外なく`viewController`に代入が行われるように配慮しています。

以下は、ご提示のコード全体の修正案です。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{

    // 生成しないかもしれないインスタンスは、Optionalにしておきましょう。
    private var myImageView:UIImageView?
    var myLabel: UILabel?
    var ex: Test! // viewDidLoad内で初期化する。

    @IBOutlet weak var status: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        ex = Test(viewController: self) // exの初期化。
        ex.ex()

    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    func test(){
        myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 100))
        if let view = myImageView { // Optional Binding
            var image : UIImage?

            image = UIImage(named: "check.png")
            view.image = image
            view.layer.position = CGPoint(x:self.view.bounds.width/2,y:self.view.bounds.height/2)

            self.view.addSubview(view)
        }
    }
}

// 小規模なクラスなら、いちいち別ファイルに起こす必要はありません。
class Test: NSObject {

    weak var viewController:ViewController!

    init(viewController: ViewController) {
        self.viewController = viewController // viewControllerに代入
    }

    func ex(){

        for var i=0 ; i<10 ; i++ {

            print("i is \(i)")

            if(i==9){
                viewController.test()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます．
色々分かっていなかった分がよくわかりました．

提案案で一度やってみたいと思います．
本当に有難うございます．

Comment: 試してみたところ，思っていた通りの動作をしました．
また，説明もとってもわかりやすく大変助かりました．
本当に有難うございました．